# How to run page object model (POM) script in browserstack?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects, browserstack, page-factory

I have a existing page object model code , I need to run my code in browser stack, but getting null pointer exception for invoked object methods inside my test method.

If I add the X-path directly in test method using driver.findElement , then element is getting clicked , but when I am importing the object reference from page factory I am getting null pointer exception

```
public class Office_Application_page extends TestBase {
public Office_Application_page() {
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

@FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='gdpr-modal-close']")
    WebElement close_btn;

public class Office_Application_test  {
    private WebDriver driver;
    Questions_id3_Page Qpage1;
    Office_Application_page Office1;
    String sheetName = "Application1";
    TestUtil testUtil;

    public Office_Application_test(){
        super();
        }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException, 
     MalformedURLException {
    testUtil = new TestUtil();
    Office1 = new Office_Application_page();
    Qpage1 = new Questions_id3_Page();

    DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    ("build", "TestNG - Sample1");

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
          new URL("https://venkateshkv2:fivhxapgnazGspyJTPnn@hub- 
    cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), 
          capability);      

    }
    @Test(priority=3, dataProvider="getApplicationTestData")
    public void Enters() throws 
    FindFailed,InterruptedException,MalformedURLException{  
    driver.get("URL");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Office1.ClickonCloseBtn();
```

Comment: Why are you calling super class constructor from 'Office_Application_test' class constructor?

Comment: What the TestBase class will do? Please format the class properly, some closing tags are missing. If possible, share the TestBase class code also so that It will help for better understanding

Comment: As pointed out, your page class extends testbase which you don't show and don't call with super() but your test class does NOT extend any class, yet calls a super().  Also, you declare your driver in the test class but do not pass it to the page class.  That is almost certainly your null pointer, but next time, please include your error trace.

Comment: @venkatesh do you got solution for this?